# How to create a Cypher Query engine within my interface?

Tags: java, swing, neo4j, cypher

I was trying to implement an easy interface to make as much queries as I need within my DB
However I couldn't figure out how to do it. The interface has a button and each time I click it I wish to have the query executed on my DB and a result back to my JTextArea

Below the working code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine; 
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil;

import static org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils.deleteRecursively;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

public static final String DB_PATH = "/Volumes/iTanioHD/Users/tanio/Desktop/ciao";

GraphDatabaseService BORO_DB;

private JPanel contentPane;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


    public Frame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 794, 653);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);


            final JTextArea queryTextArea = new JTextArea();
            queryTextArea.setBounds(25, 40, 702, 279);
            queryTextArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            queryTextArea.setText("start n=node(*) where n.name! = 'my node' return n, n.name");
            contentPane.add(queryTextArea);

            JLabel cypherQueryLabel = new JLabel("Cypher Query");
            cypherQueryLabel.setBounds(25, 12, 105, 23);
            contentPane.add(cypherQueryLabel);

            final JTextArea resultTextArea = new JTextArea();
            resultTextArea.setBounds(25, 351, 702, 171);
            resultTextArea.setEditable(false);
            resultTextArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            contentPane.add(resultTextArea);

            JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result:");
            resultLabel.setBounds(25, 323, 55, 23);

            contentPane.add(resultLabel);

            JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Execute Query");
            btnNewButton_2.setBounds(274, 540, 176, 41);
            btnNewButton_2.setVisible(true);
            contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);

            final GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );

            Neo4jEngine neo4jDB = new Neo4jEngine();
            neo4jDB.createBOROGraphOntology(db);

            btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String resultString;


                    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( db );

                    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(queryTextArea.getText());
                    resultString =result.dumpToString();

                    resultTextArea.setText(resultString);



                }
            }); 

}

}
```

Comment: why are you deleting the database every time the query executes?

Comment: To be honest I don't know, It does not make any sense to me but in the java code here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0-M04/community/cypher/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cypher/javacompat/JavaQuery.java when it executes the query it clears the DB Path

Comment: Sorry, got it.. It makes sense there because it creates the DB afterwards... anyway my problem still exists because is about visualising the result

Comment: The code you reference is from a unit test, which has to set up its environment for each isolated test. This is not a pattern that applies to real (non-test) code.

Comment: Could you actually state the (concrete) problem?

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any suggestion on how I can retrieve all the nodes created and show them in the text area? How can I manage the ExecutionResult variable to get the result back?

Comment: I have added the piece of code from List<String> up to the end of the document because the only result I gained from the result variable was or "Non-empty iterator" or "Empty iterator". I want to have all my result values shown in my JTextArea. For example If I want to ask the following query "start n=node(*) return n, n.name" I want to see the list of all my nodes and their name attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public static final String DB_PATH = "/Volumes/iTanioHD/Users/tanio/Desktop/ciao";

    private static GraphDatabaseService db;

    private JPanel contentPane;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
        registerShutdownHook(db);

        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        try {
            db.getNodeById(0).setProperty("name", "Name 0");
            db.createNode().setProperty("name", "Name 1");
            db.createNode().setProperty("name", "Name 2");
            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame frame = new Frame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphDb.shutdown();
                try {
                    FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public Frame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 794, 653);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);


        final JTextArea queryTextArea = new JTextArea();
        queryTextArea.setBounds(25, 40, 702, 279);
        queryTextArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        queryTextArea.setText("start n=node(*) return n, n.name");
        contentPane.add(queryTextArea);

        JLabel cypherQueryLabel = new JLabel("Cypher Query");
        cypherQueryLabel.setBounds(25, 12, 105, 23);
        contentPane.add(cypherQueryLabel);

        final JTextArea resultTextArea = new JTextArea();
        resultTextArea.setBounds(25, 351, 702, 171);
        resultTextArea.setEditable(false);
        resultTextArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.add(resultTextArea);

        JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Result:");
        resultLabel.setBounds(25, 323, 55, 23);

        contentPane.add(resultLabel);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Execute Query");
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(274, 540, 176, 41);
        btnNewButton_2.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);

        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(db);
                ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(queryTextArea.getText());
                resultTextArea.setText(result.dumpToString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```